# jquery code is not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have this code in my js file

```
$.post(storeurl+"/ajax/ajax-action.php", {action: 'removefromsession', id:did, pid:pid}, function(result){
    if(result){
        obj.closest("span").remove();
    }
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bow4m3xz/).

This code is working in firefox and chrome, but not working in safari, even i did not get any error in console of safari. Is there any solution to make working this code in safari?

Comment: @Tushar there is ajax only, on success, its removing span. nothing else

Comment: What does `obj` refer to , kindly add complete code in the question

Comment: @himanshuarchirayan You are confusing us by making different edits with different code. Drink water, calm down and edit it once again with right code.

Comment: @Tushar updated with fiddle. please see that fiddle in safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap the `this` with `$()` since `.closest()` is a jquery function not a plain old javascript's.

```
$(this).closest("span");
```

`this` inside `$.post` will refer the `window` object. I think probably this post call might be inside of a click event or something. Cache the this object of the clicked element in a variable then use it inside of success call back.

Comment: What `this` refers in success callback of `$.post`?

Comment: @Satpal I think OP has edited his post. This question should have asked to OP. Let me edit my answer accordingly!

Comment: You was in so much hurry to answer, thus asked you? Read @tushar's comment

Comment: please refer question again, i updated fiddle code. so it may help you to get issue

Comment: @himanshuarchirayan Again, this is plain old javascript object, wrap it with $() to make your code working. http://jsfiddle.net/bow4m3xz/1/